# Submit doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using Rails 4, Bootstrap 3 and Simple_form and for some reason the "Submit" button doesn't submit anything. It's not even generating anything in the server output for me to debug with.

Here is my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
<% if @schedule.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@schedule.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this schedule from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
    <% @schedule.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">

    <%= f.input :rating, collection: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] %>
  </br>
    <%= f.input :thought, :input_html => {:rows => 10, :cols => 85} %>
  </div>

</form>


<div class="actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, "Create", :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my Model:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :rating, :presence => true
    validates :thought, :presence => true
end
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm completely stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you have a form within a form in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">  # <--- this another form begin
  <div class="form-group">

    <%= f.input :rating, collection: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] %>
  </br>
    <%= f.input :thought, :input_html => {:rows => 10, :cols => 85} %>
  </div>

</form> # <--- this another form end
```

this code separate you form in two different forms.